# filewatcher script in ksh script

Tags: linux, shell-script, ksh, putty, sql

I wanted to edit a already created filewatcher script with the given logic

the source file path is stage path (stage/filewatcherwrap.ksh)

there are 4 files in the below given format in stage path

1. abc_xyz_07062022_120648.txt
2. abc_efg_07062022_120648.txt
3. abc_xyz_PQR_07062022_120648.txt
4. abc_efg_PQR_07062022_120648.txt

Lets assume :- files 1 and 2 belongs to A
files 2 and 3 belongs to B

I wanted to write these files to a filewatcher.txt file placed in ../temp path

while writing these files, I give the file naming as below,

1. abc_xyz_*.txt
2. abc_efg_*.txt
3. abc_xyz_PQR_*.txt
4. abc_efg_PQR_*.txt

here, the * takes the timestamp value while writing to the temp/filewatcher.txt script

I wanted to write these 4 files by taking the considering pattern matching technique given below

if there are 2 underscores, it should write both the A files
-->abc_xyz_07062022_120648.txt
-->abc_efg_07062022_120648.txt
if there are 3 underscores, it should write both the B files
-->abc_xyz_PQR_07062022_120648.txt
-->abc_efg_PQR_07062022_120648.txt

Can this be done using nested for loop..?
if returns 2 then it should write first 2 files to the temp/filewatcher.txt file
if returns 3 then it should write last 2 files to the temp/filewatcher.txt file

NOTE :- while giving abc_xyz_*.txt (it should not consider abc_xyz_PQR_*.txt file)

to check the number of underscores, I have used the below logic in putty

ls abc_xyz_*.txt|cut -d "." -f1|rev|cut -d "*" -f3-|awk -F "*" '{print NF}'

please help!

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you want files that have "PQR" to be written in group "B"?
And files that do not have "PQR" in group A?

Comment: Sorry for late reply- No, I just gave that point for an idea as 1st couple of files (1 and 2)comes from one domain and another couple of files (3 and 4) comes from another domain. because first couple of files shouldn't include PQR as I give * only for denoting timestamp @ahmadreza1383